# GA not tracking due to Unicode domain name?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have 2 domains which I track using GA and GTM.
One works fine, the other doesn't (it doesn't track any data or realtime users).

Here is a screenshot of the working one including GTA screenshot:

[image]

[image]

I think I've set up the other (not working) domain just the same, however GTA only shows a GTM tracking, but no GA tracking:

[image]

[image]

It should show 2 trackings, namely GA and GTM tracking, right? 
If it only shows the GTM tracking, it's wrong, right?

The domain that doesn't work has an Unicode name, but I'm not sure if that's the problem.

What could I investigate to find out why tracking the other domain isn't working?

This is my GTM setup:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: GA should be triggered via GTM, in your case you can see GTM loading  (in GTA) but no GA tag, that means the GA tag setup in GTM must be an issue. Could you please post your GA tag setup in GTM? (screen-shot with triggers would be helpful)

Comment: @Matus Thanks, I've added the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

Obviously, GTM will not accept the transcribed Unicode name of the domain, but it expects the "real" Unicode name, represented with Unicode characters.

Once I added the Unicode domain name in the lookup table, it worked:

[image]

The upper entry (transcribed Unicode name) could be deleted, it didn't work anyways.

Later, I removed it, and it still worked, which means that it wasn't used anyways.